# There are some TFServing metrics in Prometheus, where can I find documentation that describes them?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, tensorflow-serving

I have connected my tfserving to Prometheus and followed by that to Grafana, There are several metrics but I couldn't find description for them! all of them have followed this structure `:tensorflow:cc...` or `:tensorflow:core...` what are they?

In Prometheus many metrics are provided related to tfserving such as :
`:tensorflow:serving:request_count`,
`:tensorflow:serving:request_latency_count`,
`:tensorflow:serving:runtime_latency_count`
What is the best way to understand which one to use? I'm looking for a document that explains each metric! Google did not turn up any helpful information! I also tried to read GitHub source code but found nothing!

Answer (score 1):

I found metrics in

https://github.com/tensorflow/serving

and

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

in `metrics.cc` file